# Missing right parenthesis in jdbc

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, auto-increment, auto-generate

This is the error I'm getting:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907

I'm also getting the same error in this snippet but there isn't any redundancy of quotes:

```
String create_table = "CREATE TABLE PERSONAL_DETAILS " +
                    "( " +
                    "ID_NUM INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , " +
                    "FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL , " +
                    "LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(20) , " +
                    "MOBILE_NUMBER INT "+
                    ") ;";
statement.executeQuery(create_table);
```

Can anyone tell whats wrong with that?

Comment: You are using wrong syntax (MySQL specific) for oracle database.

Comment: Where in the [Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) did you find that?

Answer (score 2):

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907

That seems to be Oracle database.
There is no such thing like `AUTOINCREMENT` in Oracle DB.
They are using [sequences](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/views002.htm#ADMIN11792)

So in your DDL Oracle query parser is expecting `(` but found `AUTOINCREMENT`.

See [CREATE TABLE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402) syntax for more detail.